# Asp.Net Identity External Login with Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, facebook-login, identity

I use asp.net identity in my project.When user write comment and click on send i show login screen.

How can i make facebook/twitter.. login with ajax without refresh page ?

[image: Modal box]

Comment: http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/integrating-facebook-login-button-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application/

Comment: The OAuth workflow is incompatible with AJAX. The client must actually be redirected to the authentication provider, where they will authorize your application, and then be redirected back to your site. If you need to use AJAX, then you must rely on whatever API each authentication provider provides individually.