# Nesting a form element in a Bootstrap tab - looking for something cleaner

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have hacked up an AJAX sign-in dialog for my MVC application.

I am now adding support for 3rd party authentication using oauth. Oauth is "incompatible with AJAX" ([Asp.Net Identity External Login with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280263/asp-net-identity-external-login-with-ajax)), so I have to use forms.

I want my icons to appear in a row next to my other auth options, like this:

[image: Sorry to everyone, everywhere]

I find CSS unintuitive, so the easiest way I could think of to accomplish this formatting and keep it responsive is putting the form with its submit buttons in the "tabs" div that is styled with Bootstrap:

```
                <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">New Account</a></li>
                <li><span class="externalLoginText">Or login with:</span></li>

                @{
                    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="Google" name="provider" value="Google" title="Log in using your Google account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/google_plus.png" /></button>
                        <button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="LinkedIn" name="provider" value="LinkedIn" title="Log in using your LinkedIn account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/linkedin.png" /></button>
                        <button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="Facebook" name="provider" value="Facebook" title="Log in using your Facebook account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/facebook.png" /></button>

                    }
                }
            </ul>
```

It works in Chrome.

Is this likely to cause rendering problems on older browsers (nesting the form in a "ul" element)?

How do I improve this code? I know I can create a hidden form and wire up submit using JQuery. Is that the best way?

My other thought was to spoof a form submit using JQuery, ([Is there a way to submit a "fake" form using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266135/is-there-a-way-to-submit-a-fake-form-using-jquery)) but the 3rd party login requires a server-side redirect and it wasn't obvious to me how to wire that up in the context of a spoofed form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup you've provided isnt valid and will possibly cause you issues on various older browsers. The following is fairly similar and shouldnt require much change.

```
@{
    using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl }))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">New Account</a></li>
        <li><span class="externalLoginText">Or login with:</span></li>
        <li class="externalLoginTab"><button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="Google" name="provider" value="Google" title="Log in using your Google account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/google_plus.png" /></button></li>
        <li class="externalLoginTab"><button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="LinkedIn" name="provider" value="LinkedIn" title="Log in using your LinkedIn account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/linkedin.png" /></button></li>
        <li class="externalLoginTab"><button class="externalLoginButton" type="submit" id="Facebook" name="provider" value="Facebook" title="Log in using your Facebook account"><img class="externalLoginIcon" src="~/Images/facebook.png" /></button></li>
    </ul>
    }
}
```

Then you'll probably want to unset various styles of the default **<li>** tag for your social buttons.

```
.externalLoginTab {
    border: 0;
    [....]
}
```

In my opinion using javascript to provide this functionality is overkill. What you've already created is sufficient. [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: Looks better than what I have. Thanks!